# How do you run a COS VM on GCP with GPU and Private Repo

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-container-os

We're trying to run a COS VM with GPU and a container in artifact registry.

Running into several issues including

- Installing the GPU
- How to configure #cloud config
- Pulling down the container from the registry without registration
- Running the docker container afterwards

Comment: You are sort of defeating the purpose of COS - a locked-down secure container environment. I recommend using Compute Engine and configuring Docker, Container Registry access, etc manually without COS. There are many steps to install and configure everything.

Comment: Hey John! Thanks for the feedback, see a lot of your posts on here. I suppose at this point, it's virtually like running on Compute Engine anyways right? I felt like I was making full circle from Compute Engine -> COS -> And now somewhere in the middle

Comment: Thank you. Think of COS as a secure managed platform to run one container. You can do more, but then you must configure that yourself. Because of the Google software that tries to lockdown everything, I prefer to configure Compute Engine myself with the applications. For automation, I use tools like Terraform and scripts to do the same. The choice is yours, but I think you will have a much easier time not using COS, or not using COS at first. Once you know exactly what must be configured, you will have an easier time mapping that to COS.

Comment: I am expressing my opinions, and others will have different opinions. I have been working with Google and Google Cloud since their beginning and I might be a bit biased in my choices based on my experiences. With Google Cloud, there are often many ways to accomplish things.

Comment: Nah I think you're right, even though this works... The GPU config afterwards isn't exposed correctly, whereas it's generally quite easy to set up on CE in of itself (it's working now in 30 minutes which has taken at least 1 day with COS)

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this with the #cloud config solution, but the solution [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-gpus) is also incomplete.

Please see below. The future is yours. Includes gotchas like:

- Adding user to Docker user group
- Authenticating with the docker registry
- Calling with the necessary user permissions
- How to call it with cloud-config

```
#cloud-config

users:
  - name: cloudservice
    uid: 2000
    groups: docker # Add the user to the Docker group

write_files:
  - path: /etc/systemd/system/install-gpu.service
    permissions: 0644
    owner: root
    content: |
      [Unit]
      Description=Install GPU drivers
      Wants=gcr-online.target docker.socket
      After=gcr-online.target docker.socket

      [Service]
      User=root
      Type=oneshot
      ExecStart=cos-extensions install gpu
      StandardOutput=journal+console
      StandardError=journal+console
  - path: /etc/systemd/system/cloudservice.service
    permissions: 0644
    owner: root
    content: |
      [Unit]
      Description=Run a myapp GPU application container
      Requires=install-gpu.service
      After=install-gpu.service

      [Service]
      ExecStartPre=sudo -u cloudservice /usr/bin/docker-credential-gcr configure-docker --registries us-central1-docker.pkg.dev
      ExecStart=sudo -u cloudservice -E /usr/bin/docker run --rm -u 2000 --name=mycloudservice --device /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0 us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/xxxxxxxxxxx:latest
      ExecStop=sudo -u cloudservice /usr/bin/docker stop mycloudservice
      ExecStopPost=sudo -u /usr/bin/docker rm mycloudservice

runcmd:
  - systemctl daemon-reload
  - systemctl start install-gpu.service
  - systemctl start cloudservice.service
```

```
    gcloud compute instances create winner \
      --image-family cos-stable \
      --image-project cos-cloud \
      --metadata-from-file user-data=${path-to-cloudconfig.yaml} \
      --zone ${COMPUTE_ZONE} \
      --machine-type ${machinetype} \
      --boot-disk-size ${bootdisksize} --scopes cloud-platform \
      --tags ${network_tags} \
      --maintenance-policy TERMINATE --restart-on-failure \
      --machine-type ${machinetype} \
      --metadata google-logging-enabled=${googleloggingenabled},google-monitoring-enabled=${googlemonitoringenabled},cos-metrics-enabled=true \
      --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
      --accelerator type=${gpuType},count=${gpuCount} \
```